# How to create a js app the can access the text on websites and press buttons?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to build a AI that will play a game inside a browser window. All it need is to read text from the screen and press buttons. I am using chrome.

What is the easiest way to do it? Is it achiveable with chrome extensions?

Comment: You could write a userscript and execute it using ViolentMonkey, Tampermonkey, or Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for a headless browser that's work with your programming language. Examples : [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) for nodejs.